# making an analyzed string aggregatable in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, kibana

I'm having trouble with mapping a field in elasticsearch (version 5.2). The field is a string field with freetext. I want the field to be `analyzed`, and for the analyzed tokens to be aggregatable.

The problem is when I load the data to elasticsearch, the field shows as 'analyzed' but not 'aggregatable' in the kibana index settings screen.
I want to be able to aggregate the terms in the `text` field, so i can build visualisations in kibana.

This [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html) indicates that this achieveable with an `analyzed` field but I can't seem to replicate using these mappings:

```
{
  "dynamic": "true",
  "properties": 
    {
    "username": {"type" : "keyword"},
    "date": {"type": "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"},
    "text": {"type": "text","index" : "analyzed"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to aggregate by fields or by tokens? i.e. you have document with "New York". What key[s] aggregations should contain?

Comment: I need to aggregate by tokens - a 'terms aggregation'. for example, to count the number of times `York` appears in all documents.